# Do players share strategies/weaknesses of other players who were their team members

Tags: football, strategy, tactics

I was reading an interview of Luis Suarez and it made me think...

Do players share secrets, weaknesses of other players whom they played with at club level, when they go head to head in international level.

For instance, in this FIFA world cup, there are many players who are of different nations, but  play in the same club.

Won't the club manager be concerned about this?

Answer (score 1):

On an individual level Suarez of course is aware of the weaknesses of England's Glen Johnson as they probably play each other all the time in Liverpool's training ground.

He is probably also aware of, at some level, how best to defend against one of Raheem Stirlings runs into the box.

However, Uruguay's coach has almost certainly analysed the two England players as well, as have several thousand football pundits around the world.

So whether he discusses his insight with others or not is somewhat immaterial and I don't see how this knowledge would give his team a better chance of wining against England, nor do I see how this could be of concern to Brendan Rodgers.

Son't forget that these players will not exhibit the same behaviors playing for England as they do for Liverpool - that is down to the managers and coaches in the respective international teams.

What I think would be damaging to a team is to talk about what the club manager's planned tactics were going to be for the upcoming season to any team mates who play in opposing teams in the same league.

Comment: I agree to most of what you have said. But saying that these details won't give Uruguay a better chance to win is not accurate, IMO. For ex, there could be a particular trait, exhibit of a particular player, which is crucial to how he plays. You can analyse all you want, but someone who plays/train with him everyday, can give you better details. Also, at these levels, small details can make the most difference.